# How does external trigger work in an oscilloscope?

Tags: oscilloscope, trigger

I'm having hard time to find any easy explanation to understand how triggering and especially *external triggering* works.

And it is even more confusing when a function generator's SYNC/TTL output is used for that purpose.

It is not easy to illustrate in mind what is happening when using a function generator to external trigger the oscilloscope just by reading a text.

I also tried find if there is similar question which could be a duplicate but I couldn't find.

Is there an ***easy*** way to grasp or illustrate the idea behind external trigger?

Comment: Do you want to know how it functions (hint: it functions just like any other normal trigger, so first learn about those) or what you could possibly use it for?

Comment: I want to know how sync pulses are used by the scope to detect the period of an arbitrary signal.

Comment: Let's go back in time in an era where there were only analog scopes with no memory. Suppose you want to see what happens to a certain voltage when you power up your circuit. The whole transient is maybe 2 ms long. You could not see it on the scree, it's too fast. If only you could make it repeat over and over again, you could get a persistent waveform on the screen. But you also want the transient waveform to be superposed starting from the same point. So, you use a square wave to power up/down your circuit and as an external trigger. You end up with repetitive transient waveforms all in sync.

Comment: @user16307: They are not used to detect anything, they are used to trigger, that is to start display in a CRO or to start capture in a DSO

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think what would happen if the scope didn't trigger at all - it would display several cycles of a sinewave (e.g.) across the screen and then continue to display a 2nd series of sinewaves but they would not be superimposed on top of the first set of sinewaves because the chances of the sinewave frequency exactly matching the timebase scan time is very, very small. At best you would see a moving sinewave on the screen and this is useless for inspecting the waveform. Here's one slowed down: -

[image]

How would you go about trying to estimate the period of this sinewave as its roll-rate speeded up?

You need a stationary waveform so, trigger works by displaying a series of sinewaves then waiting until the sinewave amplitude is correct before updating the display: -

[image]

I've cheated a bit with the picture but the same basic thing happens. After the 1st acquisition period (aka first scope scan) there is some dead time while the scope waits for the sinewave to be exactly in phase with the original scan thus, the 2nd quisition period (aka 2nd scope scan) overlays the waveform on top of the original waveform. In a good scope the "dead time" would be very small but it can never be instantaneous because it has to wait for the waveform to be in the right position.

Here's an example of two scans of a triggered and untriggered waveform on a scope screen: -

[image]

An external input just triggers the scan.

> And it is even more confusing when a function generator's SYNC/TTL
>   output is used for that purpose.

Well, for a regular periodic waveform there is no need to use a sync output because the scope will be more than capable of self triggering and displaying a stationary waveform. However an arbitrary waveform that repeats periodically is a problem: -

[image]

Clearly, if the above waveform repeats and you want to display it on your scope you need something like an external trigger event that can ensure the waveform doesn't continually roll across the screen. That's where the sync pulses (in red) come in. Because the generator "knows" the start position of the waveform it can generate an unambiguous marker that can retrigger the scope.

Comment: "However an arbitrary waveform that repeats periodically is a problem" What do you mean by "arbitrary periodic waveform" Is that because it crosses zeros several times in a period?

Comment: It's pretty much that and also can't be reliably triggered on some unique amplitude event. See the last picture.

Comment: so do you mean sync's frequency should be exactly same with the arbitrary signal's?

Comment: "there is some dead time while the scope waits for the sinewave to be exactly in phase with the original scan". Perhaps the scope also has to forcibly wait for some other reason? Retrace in analog scope and all kind of digital stuff (processing, displaying) in analog?

Comment: @user16307 You would expect a sync pulse to be generated every time the arbitrary signal repeated. It could be a pulse or a square wave but the period of the pulse/square wave would be identical to the repeat period of the arbitrary signal. What the arbitrary waveform does between sync pulses is unrelated.

Comment: @Andyaka What I dont understand is how external trigger by using TLL pulses detect zero crossings? and what if arbitrary waveform never cross zeros?

Comment: @SredniVashtar - yes, the scope may not be instantly able to look for the waveform passing through the unique trigger point and this may cause several cycles to be "missed".

Comment: If using external trigger the arbitrary waveform passing through zero is of no consequence. If you have a signal generator that generates arbitrary waveforms its trigger output knows where the repeat point is because IT is generating both waveforms. If you have an arbitrary waveform and no trigger sourced from the generator you may be stuffed!!

Comment: @Andyaka sorry but i don't understand this. you can only use external trigger only if the arbitrary signal and sync are from the same function generator?

Comment: You can use an external trigger any time you like but if the signal generator produces a periodic (but) arbitrary signal then how can this be displayed live on the scope screen unless there is an external trigger from the thing that generated the arbitrary signal?

Comment: @Andyaka Cant you just sweep the frequency of sync(coming from another pulse generator) by using the knob?

Comment: I don't understand how that relates to a signal generator producing an arbitrary signal. How does the 2nd signal generator "lock-in" sync with the first generator? How can it?

Comment: @Andyaka Oh by saying arbitrary do you mean the frequency of the signal changes all the time? it is not fixed?

Comment: because if it is fixed i have an answer

Comment: if it is fixed: imagine ch1 of the scope is fed by a "perodic" arbitrary waveform and has 346Hz freq.; now if i use a 2nd TTL/pulse generator for the external trigger input and sweep its freq. by turning the knob slowly,  i can see a standing arbitrary wave on the screen at 346Hz. what is wrong with this?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with that and you could also trigger at 173 Hz and other sub-multiples. However, if the wave form has only one identifiable unique point before it repeats then the scope can be set (and carefully adjusted) to internal trigger and you don't need an external trigger.

Comment: @Andyaka I think I started to understand what you mean. 
"identifiable unique point before it repeats". i think this is the key point here.
if the arbitrary waveform passes 20 times from that point the scope do not know when to repeat and will false trigger?
so it really needs to know the exact "identifiable unique point before it repeats" for triggering. i hope i got it now?

Comment: It sounds like it dude, well done.

Comment: @Andyaka One "Last" question. Many function generators do not generate arbitrary waveforms but they still have TTL output. What would be the need for that?

Comment: It's an easy feature to give and can be used as a clock source in a digital circuit. I've hardly ever used that type of output!

Comment: The ttl output will have fixed amplitude and offset. If you trigger with that, then you can change the generator amplitude and offset and have the scope trigger reliably without changing the trigger level on the scope. You'll also get reliable triggering when generating signals with very small amplitude.

Answer (score 3):

Do you understand how the **internal** triggering works ? It triggers (starts the timebase) when the trigger level voltage exceeds a certain value (usual default setting, you can change that of course).

The external triggering does the same **but** on an external voltage.

There's a sync output on a function generator, it generates a square wave that is synchronized (same frequency, same phase) with the (analog) output signal of the function generator. This square wave usually has a large (5 Vpp) amplitude, that is easy for triggering :-)

You can use this signal to start the trigger on the oscilloscope, connect the sync output of the function generator to the external trigger input of the scope and let it trigger on that. Now if you observe the output signal of the function generator, the scope will always trigger even for extremely small voltages making it easier to see these.

Try looking at a 10 mV, 1 kHz sinewave signal from the function generator with and without external triggering and you will get the idea.